# Gallery image thubnail view

Tags: php, image, resize, gallery

Hi I'm using this code pull images from a folder then view it as a simple grid gallery.How can I show small thumbnail (200px*140px) from pulled images .You can see what I tried with css(320px*240px)but it still loads entire big image to that size.Pls help me.I want to reduce loading time.

```
<?php


$files = glob("images/gallery/photos/*.*");

for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)

{

$image = $files[$i];

echo '<img  src="'.$image .'"  class="group2" style="border:2px solid #666; height: 240px; width:320; margin: 5px; float: left;" />';
}

?>
```

Comment: `width:320;` px missing here

Comment: Sorry it was a type error.

Answer (score 0):

For me this code works:

```
<?php


$files = glob("images/gallery/photos/*.*");

for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)

{

$image = $files[$i];

echo '<img  src="'.$image .'"  class="group2" style="border:2px solid #666; width:200px; margin: 5px; float: left;" />';
}

?>
```

I suggest to you to remove height for img, so images are not deformed.

Comment: Does that will reduce loading time?Each image has a size of 2MB.

Comment: @maurelio79 No it doesnt. And OP didnt ask for only chrome

Comment: @safarov
I assure you that in Chrome on linux it works as well.
Anyway, you are right, infact in my code i added .px

Answer (score 0):

CSS styles are applied to the image on the client side. This means that the entire (big) image still has to be sent to the client by the server.

You can resize images on the server, by using the GD Library, which is included in PHP.

More specifically there's a method called "imagecopyresized". More documentation and an example can be found here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

You could do something like this (taken from page I linked to above, only added the header):

```
<?PHP
header("Content-type: image/png");
// File and new size
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($thumb);
?>
```

Comment: I can see that the header was actually defined in the example as well, so you can ignore the first line of "my" example.